# Fix Anaconda Python 2.7.11 symbols Mixed debugger Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, anaconda, visual-studio-debugging

I've been developing using Visual Studio for a year or so now, and have really grown to like the environment.

Recently, I've been doing bioinformatic work, and was recommended to install the Anaconda version of Python (2.7.11) due to it's usefulness for data analysis.

However, when I've made a project using a .py, I cannot seem to get the debugger to work for the life of me. It'll launch a terminal and watches, but stops and says "Python Symbols Required" and prompts me to add the folder in which my symbols would be located. I've tried pointing it to the directory in which anaconda was installed, its dll directory, or even a directory after downloading the pdb folder from python's website.

Should I resort to using regular CPython? Does anyone have a fix, or does Anaconda have some symbols files configured for python tools for Visual Studio?

I'd prefer not to use PyCharm, it's been horribly slow (Windows 10, bootcamp, Mac late 2012) and I'm not really a big fan of their debugger. I'm open to using later versions of Python/Anaconda too, but would prefer 2.7.

Thank you guys for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

In this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/NljMlWzubOs) on the Continuum forums a former Continuum employee stated that debug support is available in a paid Continuum product called "Anaconda Server". A quick search for that now (March 2016) seems to indicate that product is no longer offered, at least not by that name.